# How can I bind an ObservableCollection to a custom layout?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a custom layout called `WrapLayout` that prints objects of type `ListItem` in an ObservableCollection horizontally, instead of vertically. I think I've got the basics down, but I'm having trouble setting the ObservableCollection itelf.

I created a method called `GetListItems` that returns the desired ObservableCollection of ListItems. Previously, working with a normal ListView named `inactiveList`, I set the binded data like so:

```
ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
    new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
        App.ListItemRepo.GetListItems());
inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
```

but I can't figure out where how to add the ObservableCollection `inactiveItems` to my current code. **How can I alter my current code to specify the ListItems I want to display in my custom WrapLayout?**

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myapp">
  <local:WrapLayout x:Name="inactiveList" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Spacing="5" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public class WrapLayout : Layout<View>
{

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ListItem>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "ItemsSource",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<ListItem>),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).AddViews()
        );


    void AddViews()
    {
        Children.Clear();
        foreach (ListItem s in ItemsSource)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            label.Text = s.Name;
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
            Children.Add(label);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "Spacing",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            10.0,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).OnSizeChanged()
        );

    <!-- methods for setting styling -->

}
```

Comment: Are you setting the ItemsSource property on C# mode or using Binding? I've a bit confused by your question's text.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza My apologies, I'm fairly new to Xamarin, but I thought I was setting Binding in my C# code-behind. I'm not sure if this is relevant to your question, but I'm not using MVVM - my only two files are ListPage.xaml and ListPage.xaml.cs.

Comment: All right then. Use bindings without MVVM is too hard to deal in my opinion, but it's pretty possible. You hafta make the source as a public property. Your c# code must looks like `public ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(App.ListItemRepo.GetListItems());` and then `inactiveList.SetBinding(WrapLayout.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("inactiveItems")) ItemsSource = inactiveItems; inactiveList.BindingContext = this;`. Was it that you asked? (Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I'm getting "The name 'inactiveList' does not exist in the current context". Should I add some type of reference?

Comment: Let's discuss it on a chat: http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/Stackoverflow?password=

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Okay, what's the chat name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162195/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-joe-morano).